# Query to return rows with duplicate values based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server, the format is as follows:

[image]

I would want to get rows according to the following conditions:

- If the rows have multiple but similar `Customer_ID` and `Order_Number` then return only those rows with maximum date
- Otherwise, return the rest of the rows

So the result in this case will be row 3, 4 and 5.

Any idea on how to achieve this using SQL query? The table has no primary or unique key.

Comment: Basically you just described a unique key for your table, which you can use for identifying rows (Date, Customer_ID, Order_Number).

Comment: You can use stored procedure to achieve your request. So a procedure that will check duplicate value and return those rows with maximum date. And if not, return the others rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use window function `row_number()`

```
select * 
from 
   (
   select *, 
         row_number() over(partition by Customer_ID,Order_Number order by date desc) as rn 
   from your_table
   ) t where rn=1
```

or use co-relates subquery

```
    select * 
    from t
    where date in (
                   select max(date) 
                   from t t1 
                   where t1.Customer_ID=t.Customer_ID and t1.Order_Number=t.Order_Number
                  )
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Zaynul.